# 2 floating containers on the same line

Tags: css, css-float

I've seen a lot of questions about floats here, but they can't help me with this.

Pic: http://img818.imageshack.us/img818/7289/ewd.png
Blue box is centered relatively page, red box is on the left side of blue.
I need red and blue boxes to be on the same top line (to hide the green).

Here's html:

```
<article class="post">

  <aside class="post-meta">
    <img src="img.png">
  </aside>

  <section class="post-content">
    Content of the post.
  </section>

</article>
```

Here's scss:

```
.post {
  clear: both;

  .post-meta {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    left: -150px;
  }

  .post-content {
    float: right;
  }
}
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this:-

```
.post {
    position: relative;

.post-meta {
    background-color: red;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 200px;
}
.post-content {
    background-color: yellow;
    margin-left: 200px;
}
        // keep the size of margin-left and width of .post-meta equal...
    }
```

Working non-scss demo:- http://jsfiddle.net/UwQDT/1/

Thanks...

Comment: Hi, that's great, glad that we were able to help! If your question is answered now, please do ensure that you mark the correct answer (there's a tick icon alongside each answer - the relevant one just needs ticking). This ensures that people coming to the site in the future with a similar problem will be able to easily find the relevant answer too...

Answer (score 0):

Here it is:

```
.post {
  position: relative;

  .post-meta {
    position: absolute;
    left: -150px;
    width: 150px;
}
```